# Is it possible to get good value with last-minute flights at the airport?

Tags: air-travel, airports, budget

Oftentimes young people have great flexibility, but are on a small budget. Is it a viable scenario to save on flight costs by going to the airport and acquiring seats that have not been booked?

It should be in the airline’s interest to have those seats occupied, no matter the price. So surely by economic concerns alone, there should be a mechanism to buy these tickets?

Comment: I doubt it, overbooking is so prevalent now

Comment: I suggest to reopen this. The duplicate answer is 12 years old and a lot has changed since then. This being said, the answer is probably even more "NO" than it was 12 years ago simply because the ability of buying tickets at the airport has been significantly diminished.

Comment: Most people who buy tickets at the last minute are people who need to buy them, and are thus usually willing to pay more, so airlines usually have an incentive to raise prices for last-minute sales. This may depend a bit on the flight/destination, time, day of the week, time of the year, etc, but most airlines are pretty good nowadays at detecting early when a flight is not going to fill up and adjust prices accordingly rather in advance, to better hike them up at the last minute. And ”young people” actually aren’t the most flexible category.

Comment: @jcaron: agreed. I am definitely "super flexible" and I definitely do NOT qualify as "young people" :-)

Comment: Instead of re-opening this duplicate you can update the older question or at least see if it needs updating. (And seeing the comments here I expect the answers are still valid.)